# How to enumerate valid connections between objects in business model

Tags: combinatorics

Working as a marketer I have a number of different types of "objects" in my business model: Offers, Customers, Channels, Timeslots etc.

Some of these "objects" can be combined in interesting ways:

Customer A is eligible for offer A and can be contacted via channel A.
Customer A is not eligible for offer B …
Customer A can also be contacted via channel B, if needed.

On a conceptual level, all of the different concepts are related to each other. But on the underlying individual level, only some combinations between the dimensions are valid.

I would like to formalize this business model in a mathematical model. Can anyone please point me to the suitable areas of mathematics to read up on?

Combinatorics? Group theory? …

Comment: This is not combinatorics in the mathematical sense. Computer scientists have tried building syntactically aware frameworks for information, some of which have become widespread. Search for logic programming, object-oriented programming, (dependent) type theory, ...

Comment: Sorry for not using the correct tag. The essence of my question is what tag to use … but the platform wouldn't allow me to post a question without adding at least one tag :)

Comment: No problem, just pointing it out. I suspect the best place to post this would be [Software Engineering SE](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/), but you'd have to be more precise about what you want from your framework. Should it automatically draw conclusions from existing statements? Should it allow quick lookups and searches? Should it type-check (i.e., warn if a nonsensical statement is entered)? Should it create lorem-ipsum-like fake information for testing?

Comment: For starters … I'm just looking to find the best terminology for formulating the problems associated with these types of real world situations (combinatorial explosions etc). After that I would like to be able to show with some numbers the impact of different types of heuristic approaches … e.g. fixating one "dimension" will reduce the number of valid combinations in the model by 1 million combinations etc. Being able to reason about the problem is more important than solving it right now.